# How to use the equivalent of 'SELECT IN' in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I wanted to use something similar to a 'SELECT IN' sql statement in LINQ.

Here is my code:

```
    var FindM_IDs = (from m in db.vw_InitialLoad
                               where m.M_ID == searchString
                || m.First_Name == firstName.ToUpper()
                || m.Last_Name == lastName.ToUpper()
                || m.Home_Phone == phoneNumber
                || m.Other_Phone == phoneNumber
                || m.Text_Message_Phone == phoneNumber
                || m.Work_Phone == phoneNumber
                || m.CellularPhone == phoneNumber
                            group m by m.M_ID into g
                            select new { M_ID = g.Key }).ToList();
```

//Next find M_IDs within this query

```
IEnumerable<vw_CorrGuid> TData;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString)
                || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName)
                || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName)
                || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(phoneNumber)
                )
            {


               TData = (from e in db.vw_CorrGuid
                                          where e.M_ID.Contains(FindM_IDs)
                                          select e);



            }
```

As you imagine this statement is wrong:  `where e.Medicaid_ID.Contains(FindMedicaid_IDs)`

I've tried to Array but that is also incorrect. Your input appreciated.

Comment: It's `FindM_IDs.Contains(e.M_ID)`, but it's a duplicate anyway.

Comment: Thank you - I tried that  TData = (from e in db.vw_CorrGuid                                          
                                          where FindM_IDs.Contains(e.M_ID)
                                          select e);  and got - 
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to '<anonymous type: string M_ID>'

Comment: @AMorrisey Change `select new { M_ID = g.Key }` to `select g.Key`